# How to Save form input to database using OCtober CMS Plugin Component

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

Am trying to save user information into the database using October CMS Plugin component.

This is how the registration Page looks like registration (register.php)

```
<h3>Add User</h3>
{% component 'userregistrationform' %}
```

Here what the Plugin Looks like

```
<?php namespace Novaji\Users\Components;

use Input;
use Redirect;
use Validator;
use Novaji\Users\Models\User;
use Db;

class UsersRegistrationForm extends \Cms\Classes\ComponentBase
{
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Users Registration Form',
            'description' => 'Accept registration information from users.'
        ];
    }
    /** 
     * This Method Handles User registration
     */
    function onSave(){

        Db::table('users')->insert(
            [
                'token'     => 'Sample Token',
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                'lastname'  => Input::get('lastname'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password'),
                'user_type' => 'CUSTOMER',
                'phone'     => post('phone')
            ]
            );
    }
}
```

And the plugin's component default.htm looks like this:

```
title = "Register"
url = "/customer/register"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

[userregistrationform]
==
<form data-request="onSave" >
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/> <br>

    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" /> <br>

    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><br>

    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number"><br>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

And Plugin.php looks like this :

```
<?php namespace Novaji\Users;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{


    public function registerComponents()
    {
        return [
            'Novaji\Users\Components\UsersRegistrationForm' => 'userregistrationform'
        ];
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

It doesnt throw any error, and it didnt add the record to the database.
Please Help, I have tried everything dont seem to know whats wrong, am not even getting any error message, the form just bounces back

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to figure this out, and decided to share with anyone that might the same issue in future. 
Solution:
I added two October framework scripts just below where i added my custom Javascripts to  the `themes/author/layout/default.htm`. default.:

```
...
...
...
//html scripts before 
<script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/app.js'|theme }}"></script>
{% framework extras %}
{% scripts %}
</body>
</html>
```